# Flash DocumentClass Error #2136 in Flash CS3

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs3

I built a little game in the spare time. I've a DocumentClass and four other classes. Once I realized I could not restart the game when finished playing, I thought I should create a new instance of the main class (DocumentClass) to launch it again. The problem is that, by doing so, I get Error #2136, "The SWF file contains invalid data". What happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have to copy your whole class just to restart your game? what about resetting some variables and/or placing objects to their origin? it is pretty hard to answer this question without some code snippets.

the error you getting is too general to give you a specific solution.